# Matching and returning all strings contained within [] using regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm wanting to match all values contained within `[]` brackets using regex in javascript.

I have the following string: `[parent][0][child]`

Attempting to use the regex value: `\[[^]]*\]`

Entering both values into the [Rexex Tester](http://regexpal.com/) matches everything successfully, however when I actually implement it, `match` only returns one array key value.

**JS Code:**

```
var string = '[parent][0][child]';
regex = /\[[^]]*\]/;
match = string.match(regex);  //Returns just [0]?
```

I'm wanting `match` to return an array with all the matching values `[parent, 0, child]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative path to your end goal:

```
var str = "[parent][0][child]"
str.split(/\[|\]/).filter(Boolean)
```

outputs `["parent", "0", "child"]`

Comment: You could replace `.filter(function(s){return !!s})` with `filter(Boolean)`

Comment: Ah yes! That's brilliant

Comment: Nice solution, and a lot cleaner!  Exactly the results I was going for.

Answer (score 4):

Use modifier `/g`

And also escape the `]` inside the character class `[]`

```
regex = /\[[^\]]*\]/g;
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked.  Is there a way to only return the strings within the brackets?  I'm looking specifically for an array with `[parent,0,child]`.

Comment: `regex = /\[([^\]]*)\]/g;`

Comment: @JoeFrambach - That regex value still returns the `[]` in the results.  `match.forEach(function(key){ console.log(key); })` returns `['[parent]','[0]','[child]']`, I'm looking for `['parent','0','child']` as the results set.

Comment: @Axel Javscript doesn't support lookbehind. Otherwise it could be very easy for this. You can use Positive lookahead to check `]` at right side, and keeping left side open as `Jerry` posted a solution below. Alternately, if your input is same like the example, you can use `.split(/[\]\[]+/)` for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [g flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_Searching_With_Flags) to get more than one result and fix your regex :

```
regex = /\[[^\]]*\]/g;
```

If you want to get only the part between brackets without explicit iteration, you may do

```
var matches = string.match(regex).map(function(v){ return v.slice(1,-1) })
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a lookahead and nothing else to help get only the parts within the square brackets; assuming that you are 100% sure the strings have balanced square brackets:

```
regex = /[^\[\]]*(?=\])/g;
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/aX9gG4)

The `g` flag is the global flag to match all the possible matches.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
/[^[\[\]]+/g
```

Use it like this:

```
var string = '[parent][0][child]';
var regex = /[^[\[\]]+/g;
var matches = string.match(regex);
console.log(matches); //[parent,0,child]
```